# Printing PHP in URL

Tags: php, database, gps

I have the line of code:

```
echo '<a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q='.$caseReference['Latitude'].',-1.958862">MAP</a>';
```

However, when you click the hyperlink it doesn't print anything after the latitude. EG - ",-1.958862"

The end result I want is to take Latitude & Longitude variables off the database and generate a hyperlink to Google Maps. (Yes, i'm aware storing latitude / longitude coordinates with it's symbols in a database isn't the best way to do things).

Any ideas?

[note] - I have printed the variable previously and it isn't empty.

Comment: Put {} around your reference. {$caseReference['Latitude']}

Comment: Where is $caseReference being populated?

Comment: Are you sure that $caseReference['Latitude'] isn't empty?

Comment: Any chance you forgot to close your previous line? (;)

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($caseReference['Latitude'])`?

Comment: Previous line is closed. var_dump prints: string(15) "51°26'45.87216""

Comment: You have to remove the " or encode it.
It closes the href before you can print the longitude.

Comment: Why would it show up there? as it doesn't show two quotation marks when I print it in the table I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with that bit of code.
running this will prove it

```
$caseReference['Latitude'] = "1.555555";
echo '<a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q='.$caseReference['Latitude'].',-1.958862">MAP</a>';
exit();
```

so now you need to check the case of Latitude and the spelling.  If its all correct then try a print_r of $caseReference and check it fully.

Comment: Hi Kris, The Latitude and Longitude coordinates are printed else where on the page - with no problem.

Comment: you have a quotation mark in the latitude.  it ends the quote mark of the href.  you'll need to urlencode them or something first.

Comment: I don't understand as it doesn't show two quotation marks when I print it in the table I have?

Comment: Kris - Have it working that's to the urlencode. Many thanks. Still curious as to why it doesnt print two quotation marks in the table?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by in the table.  but your var_dump prints: string(15) "51°26'45.87216"" shows that the variable itself contains 1 apostraphe(') and one speech quote (").  anyway, glad its working.  Its always worth checking your html source coz this would have shown up there.

Comment: Sorry - I have a table which prints out all the data from the database. This includes the GPS coordinates, neither of which include two quotations. Either way, thanks.